# The getter 'stream' was called on null when open the screen and suddenly the list is showed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen which gets data from a stream and this is my initState:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initState priceList');
    _tableController.loadTables().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      priceController = PriceController(_tableController.items[0]['codigo'], 'PRICE'); // This controller returns the stream
    });

    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent ==
          scrollController.offset) {
        priceController.loadMore();
      }
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

When I tap to open the screen it throws this error:

> The getter 'stream' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: stream

and after some seconds the error goes out and the screen is showed as expected. How to not show the error?

UPDATE > Where the stream is used:

```
Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: priceController.stream,
              builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.error != null) {
                  print(snapshot.error.toString());
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                  );
                } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                else if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text('0 items!'),
                  );
                }
                else {
                  return RefreshIndicator(
                    onRefresh: priceController.refresh,
                    child: ListView.builder(
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you call stream?, in build method, you can check it if it is null.

`(stream == null) ? Container() : ....`

Comment: Maybe, priceController is null? , can you check it too?